# is it possible to save progress in Java without external files?

Tags: java, save

I am making a java game which requires saving progress. But i don't want to have external files saving progress(some game likes minecraft have a 'save' directory in which files are stored). So basically I want it to store some data which can be retrieved when the user exits and comes back again. Say, an int called *num*. So when the user 'X's out and then starts again, I would like to still have the int *number*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to persist your state , either file or database

Comment: u can use the windows registry to save same value about the state of your game

Comment: You could use the preferences API. That will obviously save the preferences on the disk, somewhere, but you won't have to care about it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/

Comment: To persist data you need to take it out of RAM, you can do this either to the local disk (as a file, in a database etc) or send it to a remote machine (where it can store it in its own RAM, or disk etc). Those are your two options. If you rule out the local disk, then a remote machine is your only option.

Comment: @samizahwan That is theoretically valid, but it breaks the run-anywhere nature of Java. Also, the registry is stored as a file on disk, in a specific system folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store data like what you are saying in Java; you have to use an external file. However, it is fairly easy to hide said file. You can save the file under appdata or under the user's directory which can be retrieved through `System.getProperty("user.home")`. I also usually start my games' directory names with a "." (like `C:/.../.minecraft/`). There are also various ways of storing that data. I personally made my own NBT (named binary tag) system, but I would recommend starting with a simple line by line `name = value` system in a config file.

Comment: Ok,thank you. I will store it like minecraft in appdata then.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not really possible.

In order for any data from your application to persist it needs to be stored somewhere. When you are running your game it is stored in the system memory, however once the game closes that memory will be re allocated by the OS so that it can be used by other programs.

If you would like to persist data between sessions then you will have to write to a file somewhere. For a quick way to save and retrive objects take a look at the Serializable interface (http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers/comments already given, we should ask what your goal is.

Because maybe your goal is, that **you don't want the user to be able to manipulate that integer?**

If that is the case, then you should store the integer on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can store your persistent state in "the cloud". Which will likely persist it to a disk somewhere anyway. But at least that way it's not on a local disk.